# Creating an instance of a class

Tags: matlab, oop, object, instantiation

Trying to create my first class in MATLAB but obviously am missing something.

So here is my class below.

```
 classdef MyBank

   properties
     Balance;
     CustName;
   end

   methods
     function BA = MyBank()
       BA.Balance = 0;
       BA.CustName = 'Mr Blogs'
     end
   end
 end
```

In the same path I have a m file. In this file I try to create an object from my class like so,

```
bank = MyBank;
```

I get the error message 'undefined function or variabel 'MyBank'? Not sure what I'm missing as the examples I have seen appear to do the same thing?

Also when typing BA in my constructor should there be any intellisense? Find it quite painful coding in Matlab.

Comment: Did you try "which MyBank" at the command line? Maybe the folder containing the .m file is not on the Matlab path

Comment: @mHelpMe: this is likely a `path` problem on your end, nothing wrong with MATLAB :)

Comment: hi & sorry for the delay in replying. When I type which MyBank I get the following answer, 'H:\Shared\MyTeam\Me\Matlab\Class_Test\MyBank.m  % MyBank constructor' Is that would I should expect to see?

Comment: show when I type path in the command line the folder mentioned above is not shown - is this why it is not working?

Comment: it is now working since I added the path to the matlab path, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Matlab doesn't understand `"`.

You shuold use `BA.CustName = 'Mr Blogs'`

Are you using Matlab or Octave? Octave understands `"`, but last time I checked `classdef` is not working.

To find the constructor with "intellisense", you should type "My" and then press tab. At least for me this works.

If this doesn't work for you, check that your file is named MyBank.m and double check if it is in your current working folder. Open the file in your edior window and execute it by pressing F5. Then a dialog should pop up, if your in another working directory.

Comment: apologies in my code I do have 'Mr Blog' not "Mr Blogs". I am using Matlab, never used Octave. File name is correct and its in the same folder as my m file

Comment: Then it has to work. Can you please type `dir` in your matlab console and paste the output here. What Matlab version are you using? Can you please also type `version` and paste the output?

Comment: dir

.            ..           MyBank.m     main_bank.m

Comment: version 8.2.0.701 (R2013b)

Comment: Sorry. I do not see why this should not work for you. At least for me, this works perfectly.

Comment: ok thanks least I know there is nothing wrong with my code. must be something going on with my matlab.

Comment: *Octave understands ", but last time I checked `classdef` is not working.* ehm..when was the last time? Just ask, because I'd like to check the default branch as classdef was merged into it. However, there are no Windows binaries of that version and since building Octave on windows is complicated, I wondered to install Linux an try to build it there. So: Any chance to get a bit `classdef` functionality in octave?

Comment: Do you need `classdef`? Object oriented programming is possible in Octave without using this new class syntax from matlab.